# Running a custom JavaScript task in the backend Marklogic server

Tags: marklogic

I'm trying to get all the collection list in datahub-staging from the backend server by runnng a gradle task.

I tried writing a below task:

```
cat myCustomJs.task 
task myJavascriptTask(type: com.marklogic.gradle.task.ServerEvalTask) {
  javascript = "cts.collections()"
}
```

But, I'm not sure how to create or run the task so that I can get the result of cts.collections(). Any leads on this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a several tasks like this set up in my build.gradle file. Here's the pattern you're looking for:

```
task getCollections(type: com.marklogic.gradle.task.MarkLogicTask) {
  doLast {
    def client = getAppConfig().newDatabaseClient()
    String request = """
      cts.collections().toArray().join("; ")
    """;

    try {
      String result
      result = client.newServerEval().javascript(request).evalAs(String.class);
      if (result != null) {
        println result
      }
    } finally {
      client.release()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Dave! Can you let me know how do I point cts.collection() to be run against data-hub-STAGING/FINAL DB?

Comment: Also, it prints only one name. I have 50 collections, but the result is just one out of 50 collections.

Comment: I just modified the code so that it joins the collection names together and prints them as one string (untested). It looks like this approach only returns the first item in a Sequence. You should also be able to return the array instead of joining, if you preferred.